# Click duplicate button using JS

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, button

Im making a movie review page, i use a button to change the qualification.

How can i get the name of the movie when i press the button?

```
<div class="container-movies" id="container-movies">
                <div class="movie">
                    <span class="text1" id="title">Transformers</span>
                    <p class="text2">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore soluta ullam officiis tempore sapiente, nesciunt veniam. Vitae explicabo labore soluta quis, omnis vero nulla, dignissimos necessitatibus repellat perferendis quisquam laboriosam.
                    </p>
                    <span class="text2">gen</span>
                    <div class="container-cal">
                        <span class="cal">4</span>
                        <button id="cal-btn">qualify</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="movie">
                    <span class="text" id="title">movie title</span>
                    <p class="text2">
                        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, sint fugit numquam dicta aperiam neque aliquam expedita ipsum sapiente assumenda rerum temporibus fuga similique sed, perspiciatis qui ipsa nihil adipisci.
                    </p>
                    <span class="text2">gen</span>
                    <div class="container-cal">
                        <span class="cal">4</span>
                        <button id="cal-btn">qualify</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This only sends me the name of the first node:

```
let cal = document.getElementById("cal-btn");
cal.addEventListener('click', getcal);
```

Comment: the movie title is in the span tag so probably need to point a document listener to that?

Comment: Ids are unique. Use class instead

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the constent of the id="title" and use it in the getcal function

```
const movieTitle = document.getElementById("title").innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("cal-btn");` will only return one element because ids are unique, you should use a class instead.

For each button, add a listener on click. Then because of the structure, search for the closest parent movie to find the title inside.

```js
for (let btn of document.getElementsByClassName("cal-btn")) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(btn.closest(".movie").querySelector(".title").textContent)
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="movie">
  <span class="title">Transformers</span>
  <button class="cal-btn">vote</button>
</div>

<div class="movie">
  <span class="title">Another film</span>
  <button class="cal-btn">vote</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the same id over and over again, in this case you should use a **class** or an **custom attribute** select all buttons and loop through them and call your function

```js
let calBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".cal-btn");

calBtns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    alert(btn.closest('.movie').querySelector('.title').innerText)
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="container-movies" id="container-movies">
<div class="movie">
    <span class="text1 title">Transformers</span>
    <p class="text2">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <span class="text2">gen</span>
    <div class="container-cal">
        <span class="cal">4</span>
        <button class="cal-btn">qualify</button>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="movie">
    <span class="text title">movie title</span>
    <p class="text2">Lorem, ipsum</p>
    <span class="text2">gen</span>
    <div class="container-cal">
        <span class="cal">4</span>
        <button class="cal-btn">qualify</button>
    </div>
</div>
```